# Why might residual series made from the same data but with different variable orientation look so different?

Tags: time-series, cointegration

Suppose two time-series vectors. In the process of testing for cointegration, one may calculate the linear combination, AKA the residual series. There is a choice: one can construct the linear combination in a $A, B$ or a $B, A$ orientation.

My intuition would be that the two residual series should be similar; like, the series are mirrored, for example. Indeed, they occasionally are. But sometimes the series are quite different. I do not understand this variability: why is it that the residual series are sometimes similar (i.e., mirrored) when the order of the variables are changed, but other times the residual series appear markedly different?

**Formally:**

Consider two time series given as follows, with the $n$ representing the nonstationary component and $\epsilon$ representing the stationary component:

$$ x_t = n_{x_t} + \epsilon_{x_t} $$

$$ y_t = n_{y_t} + \epsilon_{y_t} $$

Let the linear combination $ x_t - \gamma y_t $ be the cointegrating combination that results in a stationary time series. $\gamma$ is the cointegration coefficient and it is obtained through OLS. The implied term expansion simplifies to $n_{x_t} = \gamma n_{y_t} $.

$\gamma$ is simply a scalar obtained from the linear regression. The value differs depending on the variable orientation, so naturally the residual series are unique; but uniqueness of general shape is surprising to me. I do not see how it follows from the math, nor do I practically understand. **Ideally I would like to understand the math as well as the intuition.**

I will now share two examples that illustrate what I mean. One example shows linear combinations that appear mirrored (i.e., the linear combination of $x,y$ is the inverse of $y,x$.).

**Example 1**

This example provides two linear combinations that appear mirrored.

[image: Cointegration example 1]

**Example 2**

This example shows two linear combinations that are not mirrored, and in fact exhibit quite different behavior. Example: one residual series crosses the 4-sigma line (as measured from the historical data of the samples), whereas the other does not. This is not a trivial difference, in my opinion.

[image: Cointegration example 2]

**Order of plots in graph:**

1. Residual series 1
2. Scatter plot with line of best fit, (x,y) orientation
3. Residual series 2
4. Scatter plot with line of best fit, (y,x) orientation
5. Graph of two time-series vectors; note I shifted the y series in both to make the lines more easily comparable.

Note that the graphs are made from the same program but with different data sets, so while there may be operational errors on my part, the errors should be constant through different runs.

Finally, there is the overarching question: which orientation does one choose when the residual series significantly differ?

Comment: Isn't that essentially a question, what is the difference between regressing $y$ on $x$ versus $x$ on $y$? That must have been answered before.

Comment: @RichardHardy I don't think so; the differences of the order of regression simply changes the cointegration coefficient. While this undoubtedly changes the residual series, I fail to see how it would change the entire shape of the series. On a side note, a question on calculating a gradient may, essentially, be a question on the FTC; but it's likely an unhelpful observation.

Comment: What is FTC? Having looked at the problem once again, I still stick to the opinion expressed in my first comment.

Comment: @RichardHardy Consider posting your opinion as an answer, then. I don't really see how your observation explains the unique results I have posted in my question. I look forward to finding the answer to this.

Comment: @RichardHardy You are right, thanks for the observation. I have answered this question and may just post the answer myself.

Comment: OK, it will be interesting to read.